# Remainder of the minimax approximation polynomial - number of extrema

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Recall some definitions.

Let $f \in C [a,b]$. The *minimax polynomial* $p_n$ is the polynomial $p_n (x) $ of degree $\leq n$ that minimizes $||f-p_n||_\infty $. It can be proved that this polynomial exists and is unique. Let $r_n  = f-p_n $ be the *remainder* of the minimax polynomial, and $\delta_n=||r_n||_\infty$.

Recall the following theorem (Chebicev equioscillation theorem): *A polynomial $p_n$ of degree $\leq n$ is the minimax polynomial of $f$ if and only if there are at least n+2 points $x_0<\cdots<x_{x+1}$ in $[a,b]$ such that $r_n (x_i)=(-1)^i \cdot \pm \delta_n$*.

The remainder is called *standard remainder* if it has exactly $n$ local extrema points in $(a,b)$ and $a$ and $b$ are local extrema points.

Is it true that, if $f \in C^{n+1} [a,b]$ and $f^{(n+1)}\not = 0$ in $(a,b)$, then the remainder $r_n$ is standard?

I found it as a remark in some notes, but i can't prove it.

Thanks to all.